# How to use multiple sessions with a single connection on PostgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using PostgreSQL with Sequelize.

My app has a connection pool. I want to set a session variable (`SET session.username TO xxx`) but not sure how to make sure they won't get mixed up since I'm sharing the connection.

```
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  await sequelize.query(`SET session.username TO ${req.username}`); // in real code, we need to escape this
  next();
});

app.post('/create', (req, res)=>{
  const task = await Task.create({name: 'new task'});
  res.json(task);
});
```

I have a trigger in my db and I'm trying to have an audit log so it will add the current user to the newly created object (I don't want to pass it with every `create` statement, but I want to set it once for the duration of the session and then use it later).

Thanks in advance...